# What is the difference between a `service-name` and a `service-target`?

Tags: macos, command-line, launchd

Consider the following commands

```
# launchctl stop 
Usage: launchctl stop <service-name>
# launchctl stop com.apple.SomeService
# launchctl disable com.apple.SomeService
Usage: launchctl disable <service-target>
```

What is the difference between a service-target and a service-name? How can I learn a service-target of a service from it's service-name?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

A service target is a service name plus a target domain, which describes the context in which the service runs, e.g. whether it runs at system startup or when a particular user logs in etc.

The launchctl(1) manpage describes 6 ways of forming a service target from a service name. If you want to disable a service that runs at startup, you probably want one of these three depending on whether it's a service that runs at system startup or when you log in:

```
system/[service-name]
    Targets the system domain or a service within the system domain. The system
    domain manages the root Mach bootstrap and is considered a privileged execu-
    tion context. Anyone may read or query the system domain, but root privi-
    leges are required to make modifications.

user/<uid>/[service-name]
    Targets the user domain for the given UID or a service within that domain. A
    user domain may exist independently of a logged-in user. User domains do not
    exist on iOS.

gui/<uid>/[service-name]
    Another form of the login specifier. Rather than specifying a user-login
    domain by its ASID, this specifier targets the domain based on which user it
    is associated with and is generally more convenient.
```

You can find out the uid number for your user account like this:

```
$ id -u
502
```

Comment: Is there a way to go from the service "label" or PID displayed by `launchchtl list` to the "service-target" without trying all of these possible domains?

Comment: use `gui/<PID>/<service-name>` instead of `user/<PID>/<service-name>`

Comment: if you want to view the services associated with the pid, from launchctl list, use `launchctl print pid/<pid>` Fails sometimes with Could not print domain: 1: Operation not permitted.

Comment: If you get "Operation not permitted", try `sudo launchctl...`.