# How do I use launchctl print?

Tags: launchd

I made a launchd service file then started it. Now I want to use the `launchctl print` command but I'm not sure how.

I read: [What is the difference between a `service-name` and a `service-target`?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/166397/what-is-the-difference-between-a-service-name-and-a-service-target) and tried using the `id -u` command with the `user/` prefix but it also didn't work.

How do I use the launchtl print command with my `com.foo.http` service?

```
$ cat <<'EOF' > ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.foo.http.plist
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>Label</key>
  <string>com.foo.http</string>
  <key>ProgramArguments</key>
  <array>
    <string>/usr/local/bin/python3</string>
    <string>-m</string>
    <string>http.server</string>
    <string>3000</string>
  </array>
  <key>RunAtLoad</key>
  <true/>
  <key>KeepAlive</key>
  <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
EOF
$ launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.foo.http.plist
$ launchctl list | grep com.foo.http
66590   0   com.foo.http
$ launchctl print ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.foo.http.plist
Unrecognized target specifier. <service-target> takes a form of <domain-target>/<service-id>.
Please refer to `man launchctl` for explanation of the <domain-target> specifiers.
Usage: launchctl print <domain-target> | <service-target>
$ launchctl print com.foo.http
Unrecognized target specifier. <service-target> takes a form of <domain-target>/<service-id>.
Please refer to `man launchctl` for explanation of the <domain-target> specifiers.
Usage: launchctl print <domain-target> | <service-target>
$ launchctl print user/$(id -u)/com.foo.http
Could not find service "com.foo.http" in domain for uid: 501
$ launchctl version
Darwin Bootstrapper Version 6.0.0: Thu Apr 25 23:14:22 PDT 2019; root:libxpc_executables-1336.261.2~6/launchd/RELEASE_X86_64
```

Comment: Have you tried the `gui` type (`launchctl print gui/$(id -u)/com.foo.http`)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As mentioned by @GordonDavisson in his comment [How do I use launchctl print?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/363327/how-do-i-use-launchctl-print?noredirect=1#comment482793_363327) use this command

```
launchctl print gui/$(id -u)/com.foo.http
```

Comment: Very intuitive! :)

Comment: The command doesn't work if the plist file is not loaded. How do I print an unloaded job?

Comment: @TeddyC, just `cat` the `.plist` file?

Comment: @StephenRasku Thank you for your comment. I know I can do that, but I want to learn the syntax for the print subcommand by posting this question.

Comment: @TeddyC You can't print an unloaded job because the system isn't aware of it.  There is a section for "disabled services" for services that are loaded but disabled.